# Integrate over x with limit x

Tags: calculus, integration

This is a question from "Calculus of Several Variables" by Serge Lang on page 250.

It asks to integrate
$$
\int_0^\pi\int_0^{\color{red}x}x\sin y\; d{\color{red}x}\;dy
$$

[image]

By reversing $dx\;dy$ the answer in the book of $2+\pi^2/2$ is obtained.

I suppose this is just a typo, but I would like to check whether I might have misunderstood something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is very likely a typo.  $\int_0^x \ldots \; dx$ would be bad notation, because $x$ is being overloaded as both the variable of integration and an endpoint of the same integration.
$ \int_0^\pi \int_0^x \ldots \; dy \; dx $ makes more sense, because when you do the inner integral $\int_0^x \ldots \; dy$ you get a function of $x$.